# Rails NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class `FeatureFlagAdapter` in my `lib` folder. In some places of my code, I can reference it as `FeatureFlagAdapter.new(opts)`. However in other places, it fails with an error similar to `NameError: uninitialized constant ContactsController::FeatureFlagAdapter`. I know that I can change the reference to `::FeatureFlagAdapter.new(opts)` but there are other references to other classes/modules in the same file that aren't prefixed with the root namespace operator. So I'm wondering why this is and if there's a different approach that I can take.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Comment: Does this problem consistently happen in a reproducible manner, i.e., *every single time* you reference `FeatureFlagAdapter` from a specific class it causes the error, or does it work sometimes and then later not work?

Comment: One thing to remember is that the error message for a missing constant is slightly confusing - `uninitialized constant ContactsController::FeatureFlagAdapter` just means that Ruby started looking for the constant in the `ContractsController` module nesting. It will then walk up the module nesting until it reaches Main (the global scope). Using the scope resolution operator `::` should only really be necissicary if you need to explicily refer to constants outside of the current module nesting.

Answer (score 0):

The `lib` directory is not eager or autoloaded by default in any Rails version. This is very intentional.

You can either:

1. Move your code into an autoloaded path such as any subdirectory of `app`.
2. Require the file manually.
3. Add `/lib` [to the autoloading paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-paths). [not recommended]

See:

- [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)
- [Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Classic)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can link your modules classes adding

```
config.autoload_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib/modules]
```